# WordPress - Set a portfolio post as the landing page

Tags: wordpress

I have been tearing my hair out with this one. Someone I'm working with wants a particular portfolio piece as his landing page but when I go to `Settings->Reading` it only allows me to set a homepage from an actual page rather than a portfolio piece. It sounds a bit bizarre but to be fair, it will work with his particular theme.

He is running 3.4.1 and I'm sure there is some creative solution to this which has escaped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this by creating a custom template called front-page.php and then setting up a custom loop using WP_Query within it to pull in this Portfolio peice wherever it is (ie, if it's a custom post type, the latest post within a Portfolio category etc).

By default Wordpress will load a template with the name front-page.php in as the default home page without you having to explicitly set it as that in the back end anywhere.